# How do I change the output directory for all projects in a solution using VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, output-directory

How do I change the "Output Directory" for all of the projects under a solution, without having to go through each projects and editing under VS2012? Is there any quick way of achieving it?

Comment: No, no shortcut within the IDE that I'm aware of. You have to change it for every project. Do mindful that you're changing it for *all* build configurations. The other option, if you're brave, is to manually edit the XML-based project files.

Comment: It might cause more problems than what it solve if you don't set them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property manager to set the output directory to what you want, then set each project in the solution to inherit the default value for it.